# Using same account in two phones

Tags: pokemon-go, android

If two phones use the same google account, can I log in while other person is already playing ? Is the other person kicked out?

Comment: By *other person* do you mean two users at two different locaions using the same google account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can and none is kicked out.

I have configured it currently on both of my Android phones. The data is saved on the server, and syncs after some time in cases where you catch a Pokemon on one phone. No data is saved locally except your login info.

I have never tried giving one of the phone to another person and access the game at different location with same google account. *That might bring down a Ban situation.*

**[More Info - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4r8gux/will_i_be_able_to_access_my_pokemon_go_account/)**

Answer (score 1):

My son and i use the same account on different phones. we can't both collect pokestops at the same location but he can use it at one location while i use it at another at the same time. anything i catch appears in the caught pokemon on hos phone and vice versa. Same with pokeballs and items collected from pokestops.

Answer (score 0):

Me and the wife both have the same account on the phone. while shes is park and grabbing pokestop farm i walk around to grab further pokestop. The items are shared and if one of us catch a pokemon the other wont be able to catch the same. its a great team effort in a way.

you also cant flip the same pokestop. so there is not really abuse because someone has to walk/move and you cant double dip on anything.